# Search MXDs with specific dataSource layer using Python

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-10.3, mxd, search

I work with ArcGIS 10.3 and I try to search a specific layer (with dataSource named "D:\desktop\Project\layers\1.jpg" ) in hundred of mxd's that spread in folder "D:\PROJECTS" and it divided to hundred of sub folders, using python 2.7.8:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"D:\PROJECTS"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"): 
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if lyr.isGroupLayer == True: continue                                   
            if lyr.dataSource == r"D:\desktop\Project\layers\1.jpg":
                print mxdname, mxdname.pathway
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Finally, I want that python will print all the mxd's source name that contain the specific layer I search for.
When I run the code I get error:

```
project1.mxd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yaron.KAYAMOT\Desktop\idle.pyw", line 13, in <module>
    print mxdname, mxdname.pathway
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'pathway'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i used this code:

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import mapping as m  
from os import path, walk  

root_directory = r"D:\PROJECTS"  
path_to_find = r"F:\GIS\topo_50000\50000.sid"  
def FindMaps(root_directory, path_to_find):
maps = []  
for root, dirnames, filenames in walk(root_directory):  
    for fname in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".mxd")]:  
        mxdPath = path.join(root, fname)  
        if not path.isfile(mxdPath):  
            continue  

        mxd = m.MapDocument(mxdPath)
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
        for df in m.ListDataFrames(mxd):  
            for lyr in m.ListLayers(mxd, data_frame=df):  
                if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):  
                    if lyr.dataSource == path_to_find:  
                        print(mxdPath)  
                        maps.append(mxdPath)  
                        break            
return maps

FindMaps(root_directory, path_to_find)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the listfiles [docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000018000000):

> Returns a list of files in the current workspace based on a query string

So mxdname does not have a pathway attribute. It's simply a string of the mxd name.